# Autocomplete Textbox does not show same name entries in c#

Tags: c#

```
    private void Autocomplete() // for customer name
    {

        try
        {

           con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerName FROM Customer where flag='y' ", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            da.Fill(ds, "Customer");
           AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            int j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                col.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["CustomerName"].ToString());

            }


            txtCustomerName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
           txtCustomerName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
           txtCustomerName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            con.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Example:

I have following entries in dataset

1. Roy
2. Rony
3. Roy

and If I type R in `txtCustomerName` then it shows `Roy` and `Rony` only. It is not showing `Roy` twice.

Comment: Why do you want it to show twice if it matches the _condition_ and displays you the result at once ?

Comment: Also on a **BIG NOTE**. your code is open to **SQL INJECTION**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection Please use parameterized query for safer side.

Comment: I want to fetch ID of that customer by its name.and it is possible that two person may have same name

Answer (score 0):

Try including last names so auto complete knows that roy 1 is different than roy 3